# How to center align an inputted name (PDF export script)

Tags: javascript

hoping somebody could assist me (JS Newbie!)

I am creating a project for users to input their name on an HTML webpage and it adds it to a PDF via  .JS file. I have everything working all great except I cannot get the text to be centrally aligned - I have inputted X and Y coordinates but the text starts at this point - so looks off, especially with longer names.

Here is the code that writes the name from the input on the JS file the HTML calls upon:

firstPage.drawText(name, {
x: 70,
y: 245,
size: 35,
font: ArialFont ,
color: rgb(0, 0, 0),
});

What should I be putting into the X and Y (and is there any extra code?)

Thank you for any help, it will be VERY much appreciated!

Garry

Tried solutions found via google

Comment: Apologies, the script all went on one line and cannot get it to appear properly spaced over the lines.

Comment: in order to center align, you will need to know the total width of the text and basically just shift it to the left.  so, your x: would be no more than 70. figure out how wide each character is, then multiply by the quantity of characters divided by half

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to dial in the charWidth value, but this could be a good place to start

```js
var charWidth = 4; // as example
var inputName = 'Mr. Testing Example';
var initialPosition = 70;
var offset = inputName.length / 2 * charWidth;
var startingPosition = initialPosition - offset;
console.log(startingPosition);
firstPage.drawText(name, { x: startingPosition, y: 245, size: 35, font: ArialFont , color: rgb(0, 0, 0), });
```